# Losing context in playwrights test on JS

Tags: javascript, function, testing, cycle, playwright

My problem is as follows. I have several links on the page, which I must follow, and then return to the same page. I tried to do it in the following way:

```
const els = await page.$$('div[name="olymp"] a'); // get links on the page
        for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            await els[i].click(); // clicking on a link that leads to another page
            await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle');
            await page.click('div.floating:nth-child(1)'); 
            await page.click('div.floating:nth-child(1) div.extra a') // a link on another page that leads to the first page
        }
```

And i got error on second iteration:
`elementHandle.click: Protocol error (DOM.describeNode): Cannot find context with specified id`
Maybe someone came across a similar one?
im using Playwright v1.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on the second iteration through the loop, the element handle has been disposed. In both playwright & puppeteer resources get dumped after page commits navigation. Rather than operating on each element handle, try something like this:

```js
const linksCount = await page.$$eval('div[name="olymp"] a', (links) => links.length);
for (let i = 0; i < linksCount; i += 1) {
    await Promise.all([
        page.$$eval('div[name="olymp"] a', links => links[i].click()),
        page.waitForLoadState('networkidle')
    ]);

    await page.click('div.floating:nth-child(1)');
    await Promise.all([
        page.click('div.floating:nth-child(1) div.extra a'),
        page.waitForLoadState('networkidle')
    ]);
}
```

Note you may want to use `page.waitForNavigation` rather than `page.waitForLoadState` if in fact clicking those links leads to a navigation/page reload. Anytime you are performing some action which triggers a navigation (like clicking a link), its considered good practice to wrap it with `Promise.all` like in the above in order to prevent race conditions.

Source:

> https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-navigation
> https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2258

Comment: Thank you for your advice. A small note for the casual visitor: in `eval` you need to specify `i` in the arguments, like this: `page.$$eval('selector', (links, i) => links[i].click(), i)`.

Comment: And one more strange thing: with `waitForNavigation` i've got error: `Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click')`